# Why does one arraylist change when a copy of it is modified

Tags: java

Its probably a very simple one but its' still confusing me!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sample {
    ArrayList<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> j = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sample().go();
    }

    private void go() {

        i.add(1);
        i.add(2);
        i.add(3);

        j=i;

        i.remove(0);


        System.out.println(i + "asd" + j);
    }

}
```

I tried to print it :

```
[2, 3]asd[2, 3]
```

Why does j change when i changes? Does not happen with primitives though!

Comment: You should search for how Java deals with memory, specifically object references, and the difference between shallow/deep copying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement `j=i;` assigns the reference `j` to be the same reference as `i`.  Now both `i` and `j` refer to the same `ArrayList` object.  The removal of the 0th index is simply visible through both references.

If you would like the removal of an item in `i` not to affect the list from `j`, then create a copy of the list, instead of assigning the references:

```
j = new ArrayList<Integer>(i);
```

(It's a shallow copy, so the lists still refer to the same elements.)

Comment: And in fact, it happens for all objects (that are mutable).

Comment: In Java everything is passed by reference which is not a primitive type. (I stand corrected :) )

Comment: @meskobalazs Everything in Java is passed by value.  For objects the reference is passed, but still by value.

Comment: @meskobalazs Please see [Is Java “pass-by-reference”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Comment: True, I should have been more specific

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
j = new ArrayList<>(i);
```

or

```
Collections.copy(j, i);
```

to create a copy.

With `j = i` you only make `j` point on `i` (it's called reference). This applies to all assignments that involve objects (not primitive types like `int` or `float`)

Answer (score 1):

The Object is not cloned, just an additional object reference has been added. Since ArrayList is not immutable, any change to the object is reflected in both the object references.

Answer (score 0):

Objects and primitives work somewhat differently. Think of an object like `i` as being the name of that object. When you say `j=i` you're telling the JVM "forget about that other `ArrayList` that I said was called `j`; from now on when I refer to `j`, I mean this `ArrayList` that can also be called `i`. And indeed, that's exactly what happened: after that line, both variables refer to the same object.

Primitives work as you say. If you say `i=5; j=i; i=6`, then `j` will still be set to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You created a memory stage for j with ; j = new ArrayList<>();
 but then you said that let j refer to i's memory stage. So after j=i; any changes on i or j are going to effect both of them. Because they reference to the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

Let me do this in the following way for you:

```
ArrayList<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> j = new ArrayList<>();

// checking hash code before j = i;
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(i));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(j));

j = i;

// checking hash code after j = i;
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(i));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(j));
```

compare both the values if they are same that means after `j=i;` `ArrayList j` is now pointing to `ArrayList i`

In my machine o/p was:

```
30269696 //hashCode of i
24052850 //hashCode of j before j = i;

30269696 //hashCode of i and j are same after j = i that means they are pointing to same reference and hence change in one reflects on the other.
30269696
```